# Reassign value to different column

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe that looks like:

```
State  Area  Metal    Premium
AK     AK01  Gold     500
AK     AK01  Silver   400
AK     AK02  Gold     600
AK     AK02  Silver   500
```

I am trying to create new columns, such that AK01 is in a single row, with separate columns for each metal. Something like

```
State  Area  gold_premium  silver_premium
AK     AK01  500           400
AK     AK02  600           500
```

I was able to create the new columns using

```
df$gold_premium <- NA
df$silver_premium <- NA
```

However, I have been unable to move the values into the columns. Any advice helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `reshape` if you are with base R

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = c("State", "Area"),
  timevar = "Metal"
)
```

which gives

```
  State Area Premium.Gold Premium.Silver
1    AK AK01          500            400
3    AK AK02          600            500
```